# React - react-router-dom two Route conflict

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Here is my two Route and when I am navigate to /blogs/new BlogsShow Component also running. How to prevent that.

```
<Route path="/blogs/new" component={BlogsNew} />
<Route path="/blogs/:id" component={BlogsShow} />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap those two routes in a `<Switch>` component and the first one that matches will render *exclusively*.

For example something like this:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...code

<Switch>
    <Route path="/blogs/new" component={BlogsNew} />
    <Route path="/blogs/:id" component={BlogsShow} />
</Switch>
```

For more details see their [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).